# Execute script in current scope with native v8 code

Tags: node.js, v8

I need to execute a script that runs in the scope where it's called. Is it possible with native code?

```
var a = 5;

function test () {
  var b = 7;
  somenativelib(); // I want to use 'a' and 'b' variables in native code
}
```

Comment: Pass them as arguments?

Comment: I want to use all variables, not just 'a' and 'b'.

Comment: Then it should work out of the box if `somenativelib()` doesn't have those variables (in this case `a` and `b`) already defined. (http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/)

Comment: I thought there could be a native solution for this

Comment: What do you actually mean by 'some native solution'?

Comment: maybe we can access the scope with c++ module

Comment: Go it. Yeah, I don't know, but I don't think so. Though, interesting. I'll upvote.

Comment: Guessing here, and I am sure you may have  already tried, but I would try to pass "this"?

Comment: actually, I have a debugging module https://github.com/alidavut/locus , when you want to use this you need to call eval. I prefer to use something like 'locus()' if it's possible